# How to get thumbnail image from Android's Recent or Running Apps (Task) Info?

Tags: android

At now, I'm trying developing my own Home Launcher App on Some Development Board.
I want display the Running (or Recent) Apps List with thumbnail(snapshot).It is not thumbnail for my own apps. Running (or Recent) Apps list mean like a display list when the long pressed home button.
Actually, I'll make some functionality for Running (or Recent) Apps list with thumbnail when the click some menu on my own Home Launcher like a Apps Switcher.

Already, I got the Running (or Recent) Apps list with ActivityManager().getRunningTasks or getRecentTaskInfo() and then build the apps list. But, I don't know how to get the thumbnail for them.

I knew that need a system permission. I have no problem because of i'm using the some development board with Platform source code of Android.

Comment: Did you got the solution? if yes then please post here